# angularjs: access controller of directive

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, controller

I'm unit testing one of my directives. Its basic structure is like this

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.directive('barFoo', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        controller: function ($scope, $element) { 
              this.checkSomething = function() { .... }
        },
        link: function(scope, element) { .... }
    }
});
```

In my unit test I want to test the function 'checkSomething', so I tried

```
var element = $compile('<barFoo></barFoo>')(scope);
var controller = element.controller()
...
```

However, controller is undefined. Is it possible to access the controller of the directive ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the glue is your scope so you can do

```
controller: function ($scope, $element) { 
  this.checkSomething = function() { .... }
  $scope.controller = this;                
},
```

but i think it would be best practice  to attach every function to the scope like

```
controller: function ($scope, $element) { 
  $scope.checkSomething = function() { .... }
},
```

and then its

```
var element = $compile('<barFoo></barFoo>')(scope);
var checksomthingResult = scope.checkSomething ()
```

Comment: I wonder if attaching everything to the scope might influence performance. Or are only $scope properties checked/monitored which are bind/$watched ?

Comment: Not all of them. Only those which you have a $watch expression or a binding on them.